# Angular4 & Servlet

Tags: angular, http, servlets, post

I'm trying to send a post method to my servlet and it's not working.
I tried to enter the servlet url from my browser and i'ts working (http://localhost:8080/DemoServer/login), in angular it's not!

My Servlet :

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public login() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

My post method (TypeScript)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})
export class PostComponent {
   constructor( private http:HttpClient) {
   }

   post () {
     this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/DemoServer/login", (new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })));
   }
}
```

Comment: What messages do you see in the browser Console? In the server logs?

Comment: Is your AngularJS web application hosted on `http://localhost:8080`?

Comment: Nothing in the console @nitind

Comment: My angular4 is based on localhost:4200 and my servlet is based on localhost:8080 @shaochuancs

Comment: Browsers don't let you do such AJAX requests, unless CORS is enabled by the servlet. But even if they did, you never subscribe to the observable returned by http.post(), so you never send any request.

Comment: It looks like a CORS problem.